# Why is my font not rendering in IE11 using this CSS declaration?

Tags: css, node.js, reactjs, node-modules

I have the following CSS that is working fine in Chrome and Firefox but is not rendering in IE11. This is being loaded in from an external node module so changing this CSS declaration directly may prove to be troublesome. Any ideas? Thanks!

```
@font-face{
    font-family:'text-security-disc';
        src: url('text-security-disc-compat.eot');
        src: url('text-security-disc-compat.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
             url('text-security-disc.woff2') format('woff2'),
             url('text-security-disc-compat.ttf') format('truetype')
}
```

```
.security-question-answer--hidden {
    font-family: 'text-security-disc', 'Aspira', arial,  sans-serif;
    padding-bottom: 0.6rem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, IE does not support many of CSS features. Your problem looks like similar. If you do not know which features can be used in IE, you could check from [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#search=Font%20family)